100% of RAM used despite little usage in Windows 11
I have am running Windows 11 on a cleanly-installed computer with 32GB RAM. Both Resource Monitor and Task Manager report that 100% of my memory is used, although if you sum the memory committed by the running processes it accounts for only a tiny proportion of my memory.
Resource Monitor
Task Manager
Task Manager Performance
I've tried rebooting the computer, but the same thing happens.
Update
I rebooted into Safe Mode, and the RAM usage stayed low.
I have two user accounts on the computer. If I sign in with the first one, RAM stays normal. But I've noticed that if I sign in with the second, even if I don't open any applications (and none start automatically) RAM usage then starts linearly and fairly rapidly increasing until it gets to 100%. It takes about 2-3 minutes to reach 100%, during which time the RAM used by no processes increase (according to Task Manager and Resource Monitor) and the computer doesn't appear to be doing anything.
Here are some screenshots of RamMap:
Use Counts
Processes
Priority Summary
The lion's share of the Physical Pages appear to be active nonpaged pool:
Physical Pages
Update 2
Here are the screenshots from AutoRuns. Working user on the left, broken user on the right.
AutoRuns
Everything that the broken user runs is also run by the working user.
I'm very confused! I'm tempted to delete and recreate the broken user, but I'd like to know what the cause is.

You have provided the wrong Task Manager views. Do you have WSL or VMs running on your system? If you boot into Safe Mode is the memory usage high?

I've added a second task manager view. I don't have WSL or VMs, just a plain Windows install. I'll check Safe Mode.

Can you try running RAMMap (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap) and see if anything there is showing some big numbers?

The alternative tool to try is Poolmon (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/poolmon)

What are the differences between the two users? AutoRuns can tell you what is automatically being launched when you log into a user.

non-paged pool prob. should not be that high. I would disable or uninstall all the ASUStek software, then everything indexer and then bitdefender. I expect it is one of the ASUS programs/services. They are usually cruft anyway

Uninstalling all the ASUS software seems to have done the trick! Thank you. If you add it as an answer, I'll accept
